# VB.NET WCF using HTTP and HTTPS, detecting 302

Tags: vb.net, web-services, http, wcf, https

I have a WCF service that is consumable via HTTP and HTTPS.
We have put the HTTP support in to allow for local testing, both for http://localhost/ and to run over the network with WireShark for traffic analysis.
We want to deploy the code out in the wild via HTTPS.
We have URL Rewrite rules in place so that if anyone goes for http://foo.example.org they are redirected via a 302 to https://foo.example.org, and this works.
In the past, .NET would get upset with the 302 and send an error - now it likes to abstract that away from you and just work. This means that we are now hitting a problem when we get redirected away as we have had to change the binding security mode to `None` when using HTTP and `Transport` when using HTTPS.

Is there a way of detecting which security mode we need to use based on what the connection is actually doing, rather than the naïve approach that we currently have?

```
Public Sub DeterminineBindingSecurity(ByRef MyBinding As BasicHttpBinding, EndpointAddress As String)
    Select Case EndpointAddress.Split(":").First
        Case "https"
            MyBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
            MyBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
        Case Else
            MyBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None
            MyBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
    End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Before I do any of this bit, I use a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to interrogate the endpoint URL and update the URL

```
URL = (Await (New Net.Http.HttpClient()).GetAsync(URL)).RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString
```